# Installed SpecFlow.Allure but on server it doesn't work

Tags: c#, gradle, specflow, allure, .net-standard-2.0

I have a problem with SpecFlow Allure in local it works but on the server not. I have windows 2008 server and I using .tpl files for gradle. When I added to my tpl 
the same settings as on app.config
`

```
 <plugins>    
    <add name="Allure" type="Runtime"/></plugins><stepAssemblies>
      <stepAssembly assembly="Allure.SpecFlowPlugin"/>
    </stepAssemblies>`
```

but my server showed this error:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Ofc, if I removed from .tpl file information about Allure it works but my report is not created. Do you know any idea how to use it?

Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's not about Allure, it's about .net standard 2.0 support. Please be sure your Jenkins agent is able to build .net std 2.0 projects.